# how do I create a script which creates an alert when the user right-clicks on a specific image?

Tags: javascript

This is my first Javascript task and they want me to create this alert.
The thing is I've tried using the on-click attribute, but it doesn't work when I right-click. help?
also, do I need to disable the default context menu for this?

Comment: What have you tried googling?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onContextMenu is the event you need

HTML

```
<img oncontextmenu="myFunction()" contextmenu="mymenu">
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("You right-clicked the img");
}
```

External example can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncontextmenu.asp